# Can't change the Actionbar color when using the Style.XML (Holo Theme)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, themes

Hi,
I've been trying for a long time to change the actionbar color in a very simple basic program using the Android Studio - with no success. 
I'm using my Samsung Galaxy S4 to test it. What's wrong?

My Manifest includes this line: android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
and the Style.xml is this one:

```
**<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
</style>**
```

Comment: Check it out : https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Answer (score 0):

change name in manifest
like this

```
 @style/AppTheme to @style/MyActionBar
```